# I want to hide the logo completely when <767 px rather than make it responsive

Tags: wordpress

I'm pretty new to Wordpress modding.

At the moment, I'm using the Shift Nav plugin and I've set it to appear when viewport < 767px. This means that the original logo is there regardless of viewport size.

From the CSS I know that the class for logo is set for media all. I would like:

```
 media (max-width: 767px) { display:none; }
```

But I don't know how to override the existing css code. I've tried adding the above CSS to the CSS editor and obviously nothing happens.

I don't understand what appears to be inline css, see here:

[image]

The site is here:

[www.thegraduated.co.uk/store](http://www.thegraduated.co.uk/store)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have a style attribute of display:inline-block in your html tag. You can use !important to overwrite that.

```
.site-logo-anchor a img { display: none !important; }
```

Comment: I put this in the code:

`@media (max-width: 767px) .site-logo-anchor a img {
  display: none !important;
}`

but it still doesn't work